# how to fetch plsql table type values into refcursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to create a procedure in which another procedure is being called and it returns pl/sql table type. How to collect values of plsql table into ref cursor and return as OUT type refcursor. Please help.

Thanks!

I have this piece of Code : p_rec is table type

```
DECLARE

p_rec PORTAL_LOAD_PKG.header_tab@test_link;
p_status VARCHAR2(200);

BEGIN

DASHBOARD_PRC@test_link('XYZ LIMITED', p_rec, p_status);

END;
```

Above code is working fine but my requirement is to create a procedure which returns the values of p_rec in refcursor.

Comment: Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the tags and add an explanation of what happens when you run the code above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Finally resolved.*

First we have to create a Object and table type locally. Object definition should
 be same as your record type which is declared on remote DB.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE dashboard_obj AS OBJECT (
    i_num         VARCHAR2(500),
    desc          VARCHAR2(1000),
    od_num        VARCHAR2(200),
    i_amount      NUMBER,
    amount_paid   NUMBER,
    status        VARCHAR2(200),
    terms_date    DATE,
    i_id          NUMBER,
    v_id          NUMBER
);
```

After that create table type of that object.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tab1 IS
    TABLE OF dashboard_obj;
```

Now Create procedure :

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_test (
        recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
    ) IS

        p_rec      portal_load_pkg.header_tab@test_link;
        p_status   VARCHAR2(200);
        obj        dashboard_obj;
        v_tab      tab1 := tab1 ();
    BEGIN
        dashboard_prc@test_link ( 'XYZ LIMITED',p_rec,p_status );
        FOR i IN 1.._rec.count LOOP
            v_tab.extend;
            v_tab(v_tab.count) := dashboard_obj(p_rec(i).i_num,
                                                p_rec(i).desc,
                                                p_rec(i).od_num,
                                                p_rec(i).i_amount,
                                                p_rec(i).amount_paid,
                                                p_rec(i).status,
                                                p_rec(i).terms_date,
                                                p_rec(i).i_id,
                                                p_rec(i).v_id
                                               );

        END LOOP;

        OPEN recordset FOR SELECT
                              *
                          FROM
                              TABLE ( v_tab );

    END;
```

> If there is any other solution, please let me know. Thanks!