# select from table of varchar2

Tags: arrays, oracle

i have a type
`create or replace TYPE "CUSTOM_DATA" IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000)` .
i can assign some values and print to output without problem

```
declare
cust_data CUSTOM_DATA;
begin
cust_data:=CUSTOM_DATA('A','B','C');

 FOR i IN 1 .. cust_data.COUNT
           LOOP
              DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (cust_data(i));
           END LOOP; 

end;
```

But how can i use cust_data in `select` clause , because i will assign them to a ref cursor , how can i do this? my code below is not working

`SELECT COLUMN_VALUE as val FROM table(cust_data);`

Comment: Take a look at this link, it's very similar to what you want to do : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52676687/how-to-fetch-plsql-table-type-values-into-refcursor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works:

```sql
DECLARE
  cust_data CUSTOM_DATA;
BEGIN
  cust_data:=CUSTOM_DATA('A','B','C');

  FOR i IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE as val FROM table(cust_data))
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(i.val);
  END LOOP; 
END;
/
```

or:

```sql
DECLARE
  cust_data CUSTOM_DATA;
  cur       SYS_REFCURSOR;
  value     VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  cust_data:=CUSTOM_DATA('A','B','C');

  OPEN cur FOR
    SELECT COLUMN_VALUE as val FROM table(cust_data);

  LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO value;
    EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(value);
  END LOOP; 
END;
/
```

Which both output:

> ```
> A
> B
> C
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=69a09686afd09cf772e2c07ba05705aa)*